# Yearling badge reputation calculation

Tags: discussion, reputation, yearling-badge

The badge:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation

I'm curious to how this is calculated.

Lets say i've been active for almost a year on the site and earned 250 reputation.

Lets also say that I gave away a bounty or engaged in other activity on the site that lowered my reputation below 200 before the anniversary.

Does the system look at the net total reputation on the anniversary day, or does the system take into consideration all of the reputation EARNED, not subtracted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) entry for the Yearling badge:

> Have a reputation ≥ (number of years as an active user) × 200

Your reputation is your *current* amount; bounties and downvotes subtract from it, upvotes, accepts, accepted suggested edits and earned bounties add to it.

There is no 'earned' total that disregards bounties you awarded; the yearling badge will not be awarded if you have < 200 reputation after one year, regardless of how you ended up with that amount.